# PHP : How to calculate SignatureValue in a signed soap message?

Tags: php, xml, soap, cryptography, digital-signature

Like i said in the title, i need a way to generate the SignatureValue.
Basically, i have this peace of SignedInfo:

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-A72D6FD4C41B1F545F14700558816389"><ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>iiyihYsFMjO7QxIVCauydehAhjSm5LZlRGm3lT0VFY0=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>
```

And i need the way in PHP to produce this :

```
<ds:SignatureValue>
cGbhgNKCwrmUPXg2AKgqs1mceNcywK8BvrmmrOH627/3vadzKVnPiTn6ZaLBAcV1pYgTpNvh7RvAa8uZYXmS77YCQcYIOErbWKSTDVwBWv63d8fLm9Ljpx/1/PZrI7zSeIafXTLwPB2Lzt239ylZWPdhfg9XMhS43k4p7u1DZerVeRNSi76Q8u6jIWadDIQkn9mVEbhL5RIRGPoGJBof9QQVk42NHChdESW2RFXG7SSs2VYmdZ+IQUdEC7uPFoT/vxK2My1hGhYhvl6HNbMd5VIz/xMlDPrOCzbLWkA7oqyqSboTCObwkTwD2V20sxn6rb8mtak55zYaGXJldno66g==
</ds:SignatureValue>
```

Here is the private key :

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PS: i already tried

```
 openssl_sign($doc->C14N(true), $signature, $pkey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)
```

And i did base64 encode the $signature, but unfortunately it doesn't generate the same signature.

Comment: Hi, facing same problem, how do you make signature value out of the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by adding both DS and SOAP namespaces to the Signed info

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```